What does the graph of a $C^k$ but not $C^{k+1}$ function "look like"?
I was recently thinking about how it is, imprecisely of course, easy to characterize continuous functions as those without any "rips/tears", and differentiable functions as those without sharp turns.
But what about $C^2$ and beyond? Is there any direct and intuitive characterization that appeals to the shape of the function itself? (As opposed to just taking $k-1$ derivatives and applying the above). Let's stick to the simple case of functions $f : [a,b] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$.

I think you are out of luck. Look into the topologist's sine curve for an example of a function that is discontinuous at a point but doesn't intuitively have any rips or tears at that point (or anywhere else). So your "easy" characterization gets into trouble when $k = 1$.

I don't really agree. The TSN is defined continuously on (0,1] and clearly can't be extended in any continuous fashion to {0}. If we, say, extended it symmetrically to [-1,1]{0} via T(-x)=T(x), then I think it is clear how it is "torn" at 0. See also this post: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/925172/intuitive-characterization-of-the-graph-of-a-twice-differentiable-function

I don't think you can tell just by looking at the graph. Already $f(x) = x|x|$ looks pretty smooth to the naked eye, but it's just $C^1$, not $C^2$.
